# Подскажыте куда двигатса для запуска django

Tags: python-3.x, django-admin, virtualenv

Использую virtualenv. стартовал. на етапе создания базы получаю это:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

Использую virtualenv, запустил, создаю базу в ответ

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Comment: А после создания virtualenv ты выполнил `source venv/bin/activate`?

Comment: Стартовал: source tetstvn0/bin/activate

Comment: а после activate, если ли Django в списке `pip list` ?